# JQuery on click area - don't trigger click event when clicking specific child element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an HTML block that has a little X icon in the corner. When the user clicks within this area I call a function, but I DON'T want to call this function when clicking the X that sits within that area. Here's my example simplified:

html:

```
<ul id="team_members">
    <li class="member">
        <span>Some text</span>
        <span>Some text</span>
        <span>Some text</span>
        <i class="icon-remove"></i>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jquery:

```
$("#team_members").on('click', ".member:not(.icon-remove)", function(e) {
    //some code
    alert("clicked!");
 });
```

What I am hoping will happen, is that clicking anywhere in the "member" `<li>` will trigger my onclick function but when I click the "icon-remove" the function will NOT be triggered, as I want a different function to trigger there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you are matching a `.member` element which is not `.icon-remove` where what you want is a *child* of `.member` which is not `.icon-remove`. So you just need a space between `.member` and `:not(.icon-remove)` in the selector:

```js
$("#team_members").on('click', ".member :not(.icon-remove)", function(e) {
    //some code
    alert("clicked!");
 });
 
$("#team_members").on('click', ".member .icon-remove", function(e) {
    //some code
    alert("deleted!");
 });
```

```css
.icon-remove:after {
  content: 'delete';
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="team_members">
    <li class="member">
        <span>Some text</span>
        <span>Some text</span>
        <span>Some text</span>
        <i class="icon-remove"></i>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh that makes sense, thank you so much! That was so simple haha

Comment: @Seltonu we all do it :) glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

The selector string `".member:not(.icon-remove)"` will still match the `.member` element, so the listener will still run. Check if the clicked element - the target - to see if it's the icon or not.

```
$("#team_members").on('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.matches('.icon-remove')) {
    // icon clicked
    return;
  }
  //some code
  alert("clicked!");
);
```